# Calculator without on-screen keyboard

Tags: windows, calculator

Since everyone has limited space and I use my calc by numpad (faster),

is there any calculator (or option to the Windows 10 calculator), to hide the on-screen keyboard (the buttons with numbers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use python from a terminal window. Small footprint with no keyboard. Keep a Python terminal at bottom of screen and just click it to use. The search engine Spotlight of the Mac also will do calculations. Maybe similar app on the windows will too.  And Wolfram Alpha, a menu app, will do calculations as well using keyboard keys.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot, that basically, any cli can do it. I now messed with the system32 folder, replacing calc.exe with python resized to really small size. Since I run half of the applications by WIn+R and calc, Enter or such. I better not lose the original calc.exe :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [SpeedCrunch](https://speedcrunch.org/). It is entirely keyboard driven, fast and cross-platform. It has several [built-in Functions](https://speedcrunch.org/reference/index.html) (including Mathematical, Arithmetic and Statistical functions) You can also make some rudimentary functions which can speed up your work.

And it is also [Open Source](https://bitbucket.org/heldercorreia/speedcrunch/) and GPL licensed.

[image]

Once you get the hang of it, it speeds up your work by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell, no need to install any applications. It's like a front-end to .NET framework, so **any .NET functions** can be called from PowerShell including math functionalities. Just type the expression directly to the console and press enter, like

```
[math]::Pow([math]::Sin([math]::PI/3), 3)
1.56 + 0.23/[math]::Sqrt([math]::Log(20))
```

The main functions are from the .NET [Math class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netframework-4.8) and [Numerics class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=netframework-4.8)

Some more examples:

- Math on [**decimal** floating-point type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

  ```
  1.23d * 3.45d / 28d
  ```
- Math on **64-bit unsigned type**

  ```
  [uint64]::MaxValue/3 + (-bnot 20) + ([uint64]1 -shl 22) + (0x23 -band 0x34) # bitwise
  ```

  Windows calculator doesn't support 64-bit unsigned type in programmer mode so PowerShell is the only choice when 3<sup>rd</sup> party apps are not allowed
- [**Big integer**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) math:

  ```
  [bigint]::Pow([uint64]::MaxValue, 20)
  ```
- String formatting and base conversion

  ```
  '{0:X}' -f (0x12 + 34)
  [convert]::ToString(0x12 + 34, 16)
  ```

  Anything that [`String.Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) in .NET supports will work. For more information read about the [formatting operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f). Some examples:
- Calculate file/object sizes:

  ```
  12.5GB + 5.8MB + 1392KB          # size in bytes
  (12.5GB + 5.8MB + 1392KB)/1MB    # size in MB
  12.5e9 + 5.8e6 + 1392e3          # size in decimal units (G = 1e9, M = 1e6, K = 1e3)
  ```

[image: Demo math operations on PowerShell]