# Scientific Calculator with Fractions for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, calculator

Is there a free scientific calculator for Windows that can work with fractions? Something like having a frac-dec option and v.v? I need it to work offline and have all the usual scientific calculator functions.

(Obviously ad-free is preferred, but ad-supported is ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Precise Calculator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/preccalc/) can do that

> Precise Calculator has arbitrary precision and can calculate with complex numbers, fractions, vectors and matrices. Has more than 150 mathematical functions and statistical functions and is programmable (if, goto, print, return, for).

[image: Precise Calculator interface]

Comment: Where can I get this from?

Comment: @Burt you can navigate to the link in the answer and click download. If this helps consider clicking the green checkmark to [accept it](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the lack of a built-in graphical interface and you're OK with "computerish" notation, a great completely free option is the [**Python** programming language](https://www.python.org/). You don't have to learn any programming *per se* to use the interactive interpreter as a scientific calculator with fraction support. You do have to import various modules that are included in the standard library, such as [`fractions`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-rational-numbers-fractions) for fraction support; `decimal` for exact decimals; and `math`, `cmath`, or `statistics` for functions beyond simple arithmetic.

Without importing anything, you get basic arithmetic with either fixed-precision floating point numbers (IEEE 64-bit floats) or arbitrary-precision integers.

You can easily download free third-party packages for even more sophisticated functions as well as graphical visualization.

I like using a programming language interpreter for calculations in part because it's easy to assign names to intermediate results (much more powerful than a normal calculator's memory functions), it's easy to repeat and edit input that I've mistyped, and it's easy to write my own customized functions that aren't included with any existing calculator. That last part is heading into real computer programming, which is there if you want it, but which you can ignore if you don't need it.

Here's a sample interactive session. The `>>>` is Python's prompt where you type things in. Note that Python uses `#` as the comment character, which I've used to annotate some of the lines:

[image]

Comment: Cool answer.  I can't believe our python guru Steve Barnes didn't write this! :)

Comment: Someone else (who is also not Steve Barnes) suggested Python-as-calculator for a [different question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/44970/8558) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If trial software is acceptable then [Casio has emulators for their scientific calculators](https://edu.casio.com/products/classroom/fxesplusemuv300/) that supports all features in the real calculator including fractions. You can download from [here](https://edu.casio.com/softwarelicense/index.php) and use it for 90 days

There are also portable Casio emulators that are shared across many math forums and requires no activation but I think they're just patched versions of the original one. Use at your own risk

[image: Casio fx emulator]

There are also TI emulators but since I've never seen a TI in my life (most Asian and European countries don't use and sell TI), I can't tell if they can do fractional math or not

[image: TI emulator]

But from the [official TI-SmartView™ Emulator](https://education.ti.com/en/software/details/en/FFEA90EE7F9B4C24A6EC427622C77D09/sda-ti-smartview-ti-84-plus) [screenshot](https://education.ti.com/ar/products/computer-software/ti-smartview-30-34) it looks like yes

[image]

For some alternatives see

- [TI emulators](https://alternativeto.net/software/cemu-ti-84-ce-emulator/)
- [EMULATOR SOFTWARE](https://www.ticalc.org/programming/emulators/software.html)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft actually has its very own solution to your need in the form of Microsoft Mathematics:
https://math.microsoft.com/

There is also Smath Studio which is effectively a free alternative to MathCAD if you’ve ever used that. 
https://en.smath.com/view/SMathStudio/summary

Both are free AND ad-free when I last used them a year or so ago.

Comment: Is the microsoft one laptop compatible?

Answer (score 0):

There is [**Super Calculator**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/super-calculator/9wzdncrfj254?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), which is "free, but with in-app purchases":

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Expression Calculator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualexpcalc/) is an open-source cross-platform calculator that supports fractions and mix numbers

[image: Visual ExpressionCalculator]